# Suppose that you estimate the above model with the first difference estimation procedure in R. Will your estimator be consistent? Why?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics

$log(invest_{it})=\theta_t+z_{it}\gamma+\delta_1tax_{it}+\delta_2disaster_{it}+c_i+u_{it}$ is the model. And what about fixed effect and random effect? I went through the book and it gives the assumptions to be satisfied to be consistent, but I don't know the answer when it comes to r.